# javascript: Displayed hidden text proper width

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show hidden content in a tbody with some javascript.

Two problems.

First, I can't get my jsfiddle to work.

The script is working on my server...but it won't work with jsfiddle.  I must be doing something stupid but cannot see what.

After solving that the real problem is when it shows the content, it is not displaying it in the same width ie 100% but just length of text. Would appreciate any suggestions about what is wrong here.

http://jsfiddle.net/eSPu7/3/

same code as in fiddle:

html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:blue;width:100%;height:30px;">
            <td>This is always here no matter what</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:blue;width:100%;height:30px;">
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="showMore();">Show More</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="more" style="display:none;">
        <tr style="background-color:blue;width:100%;height:30px;">
            <td>This is hidden</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js:

```
function showMore() {
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("more").style.display="block";
}
```

UPDATE:

I updated it so fiddle now works and better illustrates the problem with blue background.  The displayed hidden text is not the same width as the other rows in the table.

Comment: on fiddle sometimes you have to change your function name to `showMore = function() {`..

Comment: try using the css attribute visible

Comment: I believe the visibility:hidden attribute shows blank space.  I would prefer nothing at all.

Comment: and if you call the function? http://jsfiddle.net/eSPu7/4/

Comment: Thoughtful, changed function and jsfiddle now works and added a background color to better illustrate problem.  Displayed text is not same width as the other text although the width of 100% would appear to be the same.

Comment: your fiddle not work here, edit your post again

Comment: accidently put fiddle in quotes.  Now clickable.

Comment: Your text is too short to occupy 100% width.

Comment: How can I make rows a standard width as the text will be different lengths.

Comment: In this fiddle, I added table width.  Top row conforms but displayed hidden one does not.  jsfiddle.net/eSPu7/6/

Comment: Do you need two 'tbody' tags, because I think that is your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/TyF8Z/

Comment: You don't even need tbody tags. Haha!

Comment: The tbody tags were because there are a bunch of rows I'd like to toggle on and off at once.  I guess I could give them all ids...

Comment: Well, that's where you prove ids useful.

Comment: Ok.  Thx!  Guess I will just toggle rows individually.  Many thanks.

Comment: Not ids. Give them the same class, and display/hide them all together using the class

Comment: What would be the js for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need 2 `tbody` sections, take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4gFJ/)

Comment: That looks like the id version.  Is there a way to do it for multiple rows with class?